# Android doesn’t connect to a hearing aid

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues

I have a hearing aid which is paired to an Android phone.
When I reset the hearing aid the connection is not initiated by Android. I have to tap on the hearing aid in Android’s Connected Devices pane to trigger Android to connect to the hearing aid.
In the global settings I noticed that ble_scan_always_enable is set to 1.
I wonder if it has to do with triggering the connection?

Phone model: Pixel 3
Android version: 12

Comment: Have you paired the hearing aid again after resetting it?

Comment: No, I haven't. The bond data is not lost by reseting the hearing aid and the Android initiates the connection when the hearing aid is tapped. It does not connect without the user's interaction.

Comment: whats the hearing aid model?